# New use of current medication for treatment of gastric ulceration

Tags: patentability, patent-infringement, patent-applications

I am Egyptian pharmacist studying for master degree in pharmacology, I have discovered new use of a current medication for treatment of gastric ulceration through my experiments on rats. What are the steps needed for having patency regarding that ?
I have to publish article to have master degree , Should i have apply for patency before publishing ?

Answer (score 1):

This is a pretty easy call. You absolutely, positively need to apply for patents before you publish. As you are at an institution of higher education, you should ask your school's intellectual property office for guidance. At least in the US, most universities have offices to pursue patent protection for technologies developed by professors and students. Although you may end up splitting eventual royalties with your institution, it generally is an excellent way to go. In fact, depending on your institution's policies, you may be required to work with their IP office. Obtaining patents incurs a significant cost and trying to do it without actual patent attorneys is either likely to fail or end up with patents which provide poor protection.

Comment: Most post-graducate programs will **require** you to go though their office to protect whatever intellectual property you develop while  in their program.

Comment: @RobertCartaino Excellent point. The questioner is in Egypt and I didn’t want to make any assumptions.